# Dúvida com matriz em Python

Tags: python, matriz

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
matrix = [[0 for x in range(2)] for y in range(10)]
```

Estou tentando implementar isso em outra linguagem, na qual não possui essa estrutura acima para criação de matriz.

Gostaria de saber se existe outra forma de escrever esse código em Python, ou de maneira genérica, em C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A estrutura em python que você mostrou desmembrada seria algo assim:

```
matrix = []
aux = []

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(2):
        aux.append(0)
    matrix.append(aux)
    aux = []
print(matrix)
```